# How to make multiple header rows stick to top when scrolled in MudTable?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

In mudtable I have two line of header on scroll need to fix the both header currently second header fixed and first header is scrolling up.

```html
<MudTable Height="200px"  CustomHeader="true" FixedHeader="true">
  <HeaderContent>
     <MudTHeadRow>
         <MudTh Class="fw-bold lh-1 border" colspan="1">A</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
     <MudTHeadRow>
        <MudTh Class="fw-bold lh-1 border" colspan="1">B</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
  </HeaderContent>
</MudTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MudTable` styles the headers with these properties.

```css
.mud-simple-table.mud-table-sticky-header * table thead * th {
    background-color: var(--mud-palette-surface);
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
}
```

Since they're all `position: sticky;`,`z-index:1` and `top:0`, that means that only the last element will be visible as they're all overlapping eachother.

You can override this by applying styles to the individual `MudTHeadRow` elements.

Here in the example below, we push the last header `3.5rem` lower so that the second last header can be seen.

```html
<MudTable Height="200px"  CustomHeader="true" FixedHeader="true">
  <HeaderContent>
     <MudTHeadRow>
         <MudTh colspan="1">A</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
     <MudTHeadRow Style="position: sticky;top: 3.5rem; z-index: 2;">
        <MudTh colspan="1">B</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
  </HeaderContent>
</MudTable>
```

---

And if you had 3 headers that you wanted be sticky then you'd have to apply styles to the last 2 elements and so on.

```html
<MudTable Height="200px"  CustomHeader="true" FixedHeader="true">
  <HeaderContent>
     <MudTHeadRow>
         <MudTh colspan="1">A</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
     <MudTHeadRow Style="position: sticky;top: 3.5rem; z-index: 2;">
        <MudTh colspan="1">B</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
        <MudTHeadRow Style="position: sticky;top: 7rem; z-index: 2;">
        <MudTh colspan="1">C</MudTh>
     </MudTHeadRow>
  </HeaderContent>
</MudTable>
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/waQRuDcNTThMdwvn)